# Oracle procedure exception compile error

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

I want write procedure which delete record, I'm pass to procedure table name and ID.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRYNIMAS(
ID NUMBER,
LENTELE VARCHAR2,
KLAIDA OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
INUSE EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (INUSE,-02292 );
BEGIN
IF LENTELE  = 'table1' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE KAT_ID = ID;

ELSE IF LENTELE  = 'table2' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PRT_ID = ID;

ELSE IF LENTELE  = 'table3' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;

ELSE IF LENTELE  = 'table4' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PR_ID = ID;

ELSE IF LENTELE  = 'table5' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PIRK_ID = ID;

ELSE IF LENTELE  = 'table6' THEN
DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;

ELSE 
KLAIDA:= 'TABLE OR RECORD NOT EXIST';

END IF;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN INUSE THEN KLAIDA:= 'Record is in usera and can not be deleted';
WHEN OTHERS THEN KLAIDA:= 'Error!';
END;
```

I'm getting compile error:

*Error(33,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null    pragma raise return select update while with       <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge*

*Error(36,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your `ELSE IF`s with `ELSIF`.

I've formatted your procedure to show Oracle is interpreting it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRYNIMAS(
  ID NUMBER,
  LENTELE VARCHAR2,
  KLAIDA OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
  INUSE EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (INUSE,-02292 );
BEGIN
  IF LENTELE  = table1 THEN
    DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE KAT_ID = ID;

  ELSE
    IF LENTELE  = table2 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PRT_ID = ID;

    ELSE
      IF LENTELE  = table3 THEN
        DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;

      ELSE
        IF LENTELE  = table4 THEN
          DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PR_ID = ID;

        ELSE 
          IF LENTELE  = table5 THEN
            DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PIRK_ID = ID;

          ELSE
            IF LENTELE  = table6 THEN
              DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;

            ELSE 
              KLAIDA:= 'TABLE OR RECORD NOT EXIST';

            END IF;

            EXCEPTION 
              WHEN INUSE THEN KLAIDA:= 'Record is in usera and can not be deleted';
              WHEN OTHERS THEN KLAIDA:= 'Error!';
            END;
```

In this case you can see that it complains because it got `EXCEPTION` when it was inside a number of `IF` statements.

You can of course fix your procedure by adding all the missing `END IF`s, but it's simpler just to use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`.

Comment: What did you try?  Replacing `ELSE IF` with `ELSIF`, or adding the missing `END IF`s?  I replaced all the `ELSE IF`s with `ELSIF`s and your procedure compiled for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest replacing the IF...ELSIF...ELSIF with a CASE statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRYNIMAS
  (ID      IN  NUMBER,
   LENTELE IN  VARCHAR2,
   KLAIDA  OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  INUSE EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (INUSE,-02292 );
BEGIN
  CASE LENTELE
    WHEN table1 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE KAT_ID = ID;
    WHEN table2 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PRT_ID = ID;
    WHEN table3 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;
    WHEN table4 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PR_ID = ID;
    WHEN table5 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE PIRK_ID = ID;
    WHEN LENTELE  = table6 THEN
      DELETE FROM KATEGORIJOS WHERE TK_ID = ID;
    ELSE 
      KLAIDA:= 'TABLE OR RECORD NOT EXIST';
  END CASE;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN INUSE THEN
    KLAIDA:= 'Record is in usera and can not be deleted';
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    KLAIDA:= 'Error!';
END TRYNIMAS;
```

I still don't know if this will compile as I have no idea what table1, table2, etc are declared as - are they strings or are they tables in the database? (If they're strings this will probably compile. If they're tables in the database you'll have to do something different).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get syntax of choice working - you still need to

1. Add an explicit commit - if the commit is not being handled by calling processes.
2. address the improper use of WHEN OTHERS

WHEN OTHERS THEN KLAIDA:= 'Error!';

This should not be used to handle expected data errors.  It is for system errors and unexpected data issues and should cause your program to fail.

```
WHEN OTHERS 
THEN 
  ROLLBACK;
  KLAIDA:= 'Error!';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
  RAISE;
END;
```